# How to import a list from another python file

Tags: python

I just started programming in Python so I would love a detailed explanation.
Let's say I have a list of words at file number 1:

```
list=["leaf","cream","pickles","vinegar","gouda","almond","fire","orbit","spider","symbol"]
```

In a cache called "Random Words".

Now I'm coding a different file (file 2) called "The Selected Word".
 I want to import a different word from file 1 each time I run file 2.
What command should I write?
I tried this:

```
word = random.choice.open("random words","w")
print(word)
```

And it didn't work ...

Comment: in file2.py import your list: from .file1 import list

Answer (score 7):

to make things simple make sure randomwords.py and theselectedword.py are in the same folder and directory.
in randomwords.py

```
list_of_words = ['age','body',.... etc]
#do not use 'list' to name a variable or object,so as not to override the list function called list()
```

then in theselectedword.py

```
from randomwords import list_of_words

import random
word = random.choice(list_of_words)
print(word)
```

Comment: `list` should not be used as name of variable

Comment: does that hit the nail on the head @ Olvin

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pythons module system for this task:

Save list in python script, "Random_Words.py":

```
my_list = ["leaf"
           , "cream"
           , "pickles"
           , "vinegar"
           , "gouda"
           , "almond"
           , "fire"
           , "orbit"
           , "spider"
           , "symbol"
            ]
```

And now import this script as a module in the other program, "The_Selected_Word.py":

```
from Random_Words import my_list

word = random.choice(my_list)
print(word)
```

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name. And [read this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't import Python files using any file-open library, like

```py
open('random_words', 'w')
# IT DOESN'T WORK
```

Because you will not be able to use code from these files

But you can use "import" instead:

```py
import random_words
```

Or:

```py
from random_words import words
```

2. Don't use "list" name for any of your variable, because it's special Python word

```py
list = ['some word', 'word']
# IT DOESN'T WORK
```

Use another name instead:

```py
words = ['some_word', 'word']
```

3. Let's combine this:

```
# random_words.py

words = [
"leaf",
"cream",
"pickles",
"vinegar",
"gouda",
"almond",
"fire",
"orbit",
"spider",
"symbol"
]
```

```py
# the_selected_word.py

from random_words import words
print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, from your question i am assuming that you have two files, 1st is `file1.py` and 2nd is `file2.py`.
You have a list named `list` in `file1.py` and you want to import `list` to `file2.py` and from this list, you want to get random words.

so for this, you can do in `file2.py`

```
from file1 import list
import random

words = random.choice(list)
print(words)
```

Comment: and as @Olvin said in comments, do not use `list` as a variable name because it is python function to create list eg `l = list()`. Here l is now an empty list.