# how to make discord.py bot respond with lists from other python file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

the following is an example of what would be in "lists.py"

```
good = ["eminem", "blackbear, "dua lipa", "daya", "ariana grande"]

bad = ["machine gun kelly", "sam smith", "harry styles", "the weekend"]
```

the following is an example of what would be in "main.py"

```
  if message.content.startswith("b.get") and message.author.id == 449504378307739648:
   fetchlist = msg.split("b.get ",1)[1]
   #stuck here
   await message.channel.send(fetchlist)
```

how can this be coded for "b.get good" to send the "good" list in lists.py and "b.get bad" to send the "bad" lists without doing this:

```
if fetchlist == "good"
 await message.channel.send(good)
if fetchlist == "bad"
 await message.channel.send(bad)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a list from another python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990329/how-to-import-a-list-from-another-python-file)

Comment: Could you do `from lists.py import good` and `from lists.py import bad`?